# Using recursive function to iterate over nested object, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, ecmascript-6, nested-object

I need to iterate over a nested function and find the sub-object that has the same key as I want. here is the code:

```
 const searchObject = (obj, label) => {
        const object = Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            if(label === key) {
                return obj[key];
            } else if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
                const value = searchObject(obj[key], label);
                if(value) return value;
            }
        });
        return object;
    };
```

I searched a lot and I found many people are recommending this way but I dont know why I get **undefined** when I log console.log(searchObject(obj, "Intercept")).  (I am using React framework)

Comment: You are returning within  `.forEach`. That won't work.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that null also has a type of 'object', so you may need to check for that as well.

Comment: Why don't you post your data object here, at least a sample?

Answer (score 1):

[forEach returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
 const searchObject = (obj, label) => {
        var object = {}
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            if(label === key) {
                object = obj[key];
            } else if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
                const value = searchObject(obj[key], label);
                if(value) object = return value;
            }
        });
        return object;
    };
```

Comment: unfortunately map() did not solve the problem. most of the time it returns arrays of undefined and sometimes it has the object I am looking for. But this should not be the right way.

Comment: You probably want `Array#find` then. Can you post your input and expected output as a [mcve]?